# Putting one Component in front of another (higher zIndex) dynamically

Tags: react-native

So there are two components sort of like this:

```
<View>
  <Component1 />
  <Component2 />
</View>
```

Both, Component1 & Component2 can be dragged and dropped within the View. By default, Component2 will render above the Component1 (since it is above in the stack). I want to make it so that whenever I press Component1 (for drag and drop) it dynamically comes infront of Component2 (Higher zIndex) and if I press Component1 and drag and drop, Component1 comes infront of Component2.

Anyone has any idea on how this can be done?

Edit 1:

I'm using zIndex, but for some reason it's working on iOS but not working on Android. Here's the basic code:

```
<View>
    <View style={{position:'absolute',zIndex:2,backgroundColor:'red',width:500,height:500}}/>
    <View style={{position:'absolute',zIndex:1,backgroundColor:'green',width:500,height:500,marginLeft:50}}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting dynamic `zIndex` for child components looks like the way to go. ([zIndex on docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#zindex))

I would store the `zIndex`es of each child in the state. And I would wrap `Component1` and `Component2` with a touchable component if they are not already. When dragging & dropping starts, I'd update the `zIndex` stored in the state so that the required child would have higher `zIndex`.

Since I don't exactly know how you structured the components and their layouts, I am unable to provide a example code piece.

**EDIT**

**Workaround for missing zIndex implementation on Android**

I'd go something like this, if nothing else works:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  child: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
  },
});

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      reverseOrderOfChildren: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const firstChild = <View style={[style.child, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]} />
    const secondChild = <View style={[style.child, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]} />

    if (this.state.reverseOrderOfChildren) {
      return (
        <View style={style.wrapper}>
          {secondChild}

          {firstChild}
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={style.wrapper}>
        {firstChild}

        {secondChild}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried setting zIndex dynamically but for some reason I just figured out that it's working on iOS but not on android. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: There is an somehow-relevant issue on github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8968 may it be about it?

Comment: They said it got fixed in react native v0.48 but I'm still getting the problem on v0.48.2. I've added a little code for you to understand my issue more.

Comment: Before `zIndex` style option was introduced, the `View` that rendered later (i mean the one comes literally after the other one, on the code) used to have the higher `zIndex`. Looks like `zIndex` implementation on android doesn't work and old behaviour is still valid (I didn't run and check your code, I am considering your experience). Is changing the order of the rendered Views an option for you?

Comment: I need zIndex to be set dynamically between those two components. So it's like if I press box1, box1 should get a higher zIndex than box2 and vice versa.

Comment: I got that part, if you have only two Views that need to ordered, you can use a dirty hack. Duplicate the code that renders children Views, change the order, and render according to the state. If you don't get the idea I can update my answer with an example.

Comment: I added an example to my answer, it is not perfect but it should solve your problem OK if you have only two children.